# Fetch unique values using visual workflow

Tags: picklist, flow, visual-workflow

I am creating a dependent picklist in visual workflow using dynamic choice elements. The data source for picklists is database. When I fetch values I am getting duplicate values as it is in the database. Any way to fetch only the unique values.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at the new SObject Collection and Loop features coming in Summer'14 for this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a custom object for maintaining these picklist values and dependencies?  Then you can reference the custom object in your dynamic choices and get unique values.